# Microtime в PHP?

Tags: php

Микросекунда это 1/миллионная секунды, но в php при microtime(true) никогда не удавалось увидеть значение больше 9999 после точки. Это внутреннее ограничение языка, системы? Или там где-то есть настройка которая весь миллион позволяет включить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с [количеством значащих цифр](http://php.net/precision), отображаемых для чисел с плавающей точкой.

В php.ini поменяйте

```
precision = 14
```

на

```
precision = 16
```

например и снова посмотрите результаты работы функции.

Answer (score 3):

Оставлю-ка я этот ответ просто в назидание.

Я сначала подумал, что такого понятия, как точка в double просто нет - есть экспонента и мантисса, поэтому надо проверить это дело в консоли и написать, что этого не может быть

```
etki@aves:/tmp > php -r 'var_dump(microtime());'
Command line code:1:
string(21) "0.74330500 1489303949"
etki@aves:/tmp > php -r 'var_dump(microtime());'
Command line code:1:
string(21) "0.43651800 1489303950"
etki@aves:/tmp > php -r 'var_dump(microtime());'
Command line code:1:
string(21) "0.26226800 1489303951"
```

И на этом этапе, видя 00 в конце дробной части секунд, сходу принимаю это за округление до сотни микросекунд (что, конечно, неверно - округление идет до одной микросекунды). Дальше - оригинальный ответ с небольшой редакцией

Чтобы найти причины поведения, можно залезть в исходники PHP. На [третьей странице поиска](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?p=3&q=microtime&utf8=%E2%9C%93) по очевидном запросу находится то, что нам нужно: `ext/standard/microtime.c`. Дальше можно проследить, что за функция вызывается при вызове microtime: [_php_gettimeofday](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.2/ext/standard/microtime.c#L54), а она, в свою очередь, вызывает gettimeofday из C API.

Здесь уже можно отправлять в гугл запрос gettimeofday resolution и получать [много](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98/2908793) [разных](http://www.unix.com/programming/52421-smallest-resolution-using-gettimeofday-c.html) [ссылок](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13231654/2908793) на en.so и [не только](http://www.unix.com/programming/52421-smallest-resolution-using-gettimeofday-c.html), в которых будут ссылаться на статьи по работе часов в Linux, но можно пойти еще дальше

- [do_gettimeofday](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L1175)
- [getnstimeofday64](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L710)
- [__getnstimeofday64](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L677)
- [timekeeping_get_ns](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L312)
- [timekeeping_get_delta](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timekeeping.c#L161)

Здесь уже начинается темная магия, для которой все-таки надо понимать ядро Linux получше меня, но можно отметить, что используется некоторая структура [clocksource](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/clocksource.h#L22):

```
* @read:               returns a cycle value, passes clocksource as argument
...
* @mult:               cycle to nanosecond multiplier
...
```

Очевидно, что clocksource считает какие-то циклы, которые затем преобразует в наносекунды путем умножения и деления (видимо, это абстракция над TSC в процессоре), а само количество наносекунд считается в виде long, из которого потом составляется вывод microtime. Таким образом можно сказать, что

- PHP целиком и полностью полагается на API операционной системы, и не налагает каких-либо ограничений на возвращаемые данные (т.е. возможно, чтот тот же самый код на том же железе на новых версиях ОС будет выдавать иные значения)
- Вывод microtime довольно странный. Если установить по совету @Visman precision в достаточно большое число, то количество ненулевых цифр после запятой может быть довольно большим:

  ```
  etki@aves:/tmp > php -r 'var_dump(microtime(true));'
  Command line code:1:
  double(1489304519.9542729854583740234375)
  ```

  Это явно излишняя точность, которую машина не может обеспечить; однако вывод `microtime()` по-прежнему выдает нули в конце дробной части:

  ```
  etki@aves:/tmp > php -r 'var_dump(microtime());'
  Command line code:1:
  string(21) "0.26226800 1489303951"
  ```

  Возможно, это происходит в результате конвертации в double, но делать какие-то выводы не берусь

В целом хотел бы заметить, что время - это очень скользкая тема, и полагаться на вывод microtime и аналогичных функций для организации логики не стоит (потому что они подвержены leap seconds, они имеют право возвращать на последующих вызовах значения меньше текущих, и т.д.)

Comment: Боже, какой позор. Я перепутал изначальный вывод microtime(), редакция в пути.

Comment: Человек будь моим учителем! )) Очень круто ответ, спасибо!